# Flutter WebView App does not respond to my touch events

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, webview, smartphone

I am studying about flutter, and I am trying to make webview app by using flutter. First, here is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';
import 'dart:async';

class flutterHome extends StatefulWidget {
   @override
   _ flutterHomeState createState() => _flutterHomeState();
}

class _flutterHomeState extends State<flutterHome> {
   Completer<WebViewController> _controller = Completer<WebViewController>();
   final Set<String> _favorites = Set<String>();

   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
         body: WebView(
         initialUrl: 'https://www.google.com',
         onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
           _controller.complete(webViewController);
         },
         ),
      );
   }
}
```

When I execute this code, it loads initial url successfully at first, but the size of the webview does not fit to devices where it is running. Also, I cannot scroll or touch anything in the website. I have struggled for this about 5 or 6 days, but I have no idea why this code doesn't work. Can somebody help?

Comment: Same code is working fine in my phone even I'm able to interact with web page. Once try adding latest dependency i.e "webview_flutter: ^0.3.22+1".

Comment: I'm experiencing this in 1.0.0.